# Collision of two moving lines (3D)

Tags: linear-algebra, 3d, collision-detection

I have two lines / edges moving with linear velocity in timesteps. How do I determine whether the lines collide / intersect in the intervening period?

My lines are (P1,Q1) and (P2,Q2). The endpoints move from their original position at t=0 to a new position at t=1 in a straight path / linear motion.

[image: Example]

Comment: I notice that your question has as one of its tags <3d> but I see nothing in it to indicate that the environment is a 3-space. Also, when you write of lines, do you actually mean “line segments?”

Comment: Yes and yes. If thought that this was obviosu from the title and since line intersection in 2D is pretty simple.

Even in 2D, some pointers on how to solve this (i.e possible collision of line segments during a timestep) would be appreciated.